# ImportError: Install keras_contrib in order to use instance normalization

Tags: python

ImportError: Install keras_contrib in order to use instance normalization. This is the error message:

[image]

I went to the website that suggested and I get this:

[image]

Then I ran the code again and got the same error like in image 1

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stackoverflow, pleas upload the code in which you are facing the problem so that we can look at the cause and not just the symptoms

Answer (score 0):

from keras_contrib.layers.normalization.instancenormalization import InstanceNormalization